# Weird java.net.SocketException behaviour

Tags: java, windows, udp, datagram

I am distributing an app which binds to 1200 port to listen for UDP packets. App is installed on ~50 machines which are set to auto restart in 7:30AM and to auto login some specific user and when that user is logging in to auto start my app. 
Problem is that on that morning machine restart about 5 machines wont start my app because my app fails with `java.net.SocketException: Already bound exception` for that 1200 port. But when you then login to the machine and try starting the app manually it starts without problems.

There is nothing unusual installed on this machines, some vnc server, and few other apps that should not use this port. Can it be that while Windows is booting it randomly takes this port or something like that? Because I only experienced this behaviour when machine is restarted, not when that user is logging off and than back in (which kills and starts my app).

I am using standard `DatagramChannel` to bind to the port, nothing exotic.

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(1200));
```

Problematic machines are different every day, not always the same ones.

Comment: I'd say, try to wait 1 extra minute or so after your application gets auto-launched before trying to connect. Because, that is really what windows is all about. Lettings you things do, without the OS being ready and fully booted.

Comment: a)Make the system log all listening programs/ports on exception. This will let you see what else may have it bound.

b)Add a timeout/retry on exception. If it's random machines, chances are its just trying to run too early.